# Error setting up persistent data storage in Shiny apps - R

Tags: r

I have created an app that works perfectly using the data stored in my pc. However, when I publish the app via shinyapps.io it doesn't work. I found out some possible solutions in the link below

*https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html*

Because of permissions in my pc I decided to use the MongoDB option, but I always get the same error when trying to connect to the database.

```
*options(mongodb = list(
  "host" = "ds225010.mlab.com:25010/pmsanchezb", # will be like: ds131041.mlab.com:31041
  "username" = "pmsanchezb",
  "password" = "#############"
))
db_name <- "pmsanchezb" # whatever you called the database when you set it up
db <- mongo(collection = "data",
            url = sprintf("mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds225010.mlab.com:25010/pmsanchezb",
                          options()$mongodb$username,
                          options()$mongodb$password,
                          options()$mongodb$host,
                          db_name))*
```

I have checked many times the password and other options but it seems it appears always the same mistake.

> Error: Authentication failed.

If anyone have any idea or suggestion what could cause the error I would be grateful. The values that appear in the code above are copied directly from the database created in Mlab.

Comment: Can you connect to the database through a MongoDB UI or shell using that connection string?